# Pretty sfinae with static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I am trying to create an event manager that will register receivers. To do this, I want to be able to construct a `std::function` with a given parameter. However, I want the error to be easily understandable to the end user. I thought of doing this with SFINAE and a type dependent `static_assert` but I am having trouble because the two functions become ambiguous on a valid input. Furthermore, I want to have multiple error reasons that the user can receive. Since there are two failure points (providing an invalid functor and providing the wrong event type) I want there to be a total of 3 functions, the first being the one for proper input and then improper inputs trickling down (instead of having 4 functions for each combination of state).

This would be solvable with c++17's `if constexpr` but my target platform is c++14 so other methods will need to be used.

My current attempt (which only checks for one error state):

```
template <typename Event, typename Func>
auto register(Func &&func)
-> decltype(func_t<Event>(std::forward<Func>(func)), void()) {}

template <typename Event, typename Func>
void register(Func &&) {
    static_assert(meta::delay_v<Func>, "Function object cant be constructed by function");
}
```

`meta::delay_v` equals to `false` but is dependent on its parameters, so the `static_assert` is not triggered until the function is called.

---

A more involved use case would be

```
template <typename Event, typename Func>
auto register(Func &&func)
-> decltype(func_t<Event>(std::forward<Func>(func))
            ,meta::is_in_tuple<Event, Events_Tuple>
            ,void()) {}
```

And so if the first test fails (the `func_t` construction) then we would `static_assert` about that, and if the second test fails we would `static_assert` about that. So if the first test fails, regardless of the second test, we fail some static assert. Then, if the first test passes, we would print about failing the second test. Not having to rewrite the tests would be a very nice bonus.

Comment: Use tag dispatch + simple overloading, or implement/use the [detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Comment: @ildjarn With detection idiom wouldn't I need to have 4 functions for 2 possible error points? Because for each function I would have to check one specific combination of all error points. Unless I'm not seeing something which would let me have just 3 functions for 2 errors (and 4 functions for 3 errors).

Comment: You would write 1 + _ErrorN_ functions; the public API that dispatches to the correct error/success functions is universal boilerplate that you write once and use for each set of functions.

Comment: Ah yes I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Note: This started as a comment on [the OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41673423/636019) but grew a bit large; apologies for being derivative.</sub>

I suggest the following restructuring:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename PredT, typename F>
    struct fail_cond {
        using pred_type = PredT;
        F callback;
    };
    struct success_tag { };

    template<typename F>
    constexpr decltype(auto) eval_if(int, fail_cond<success_tag, F>&& fc) {
        return fc.callback();
    }

    template<
        typename FC, typename... FCs,
        typename PredT = typename std::decay_t<FC>::pred_type,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<std::false_type, PredT>{}, int> = 0
    >
    constexpr decltype(auto) eval_if(int, FC&& fc, FCs&&...) {
        return fc.callback(PredT{});
    }

    template<typename FC, typename... FCs>
    constexpr decltype(auto) eval_if(long, FC&&, FCs&&... fcs) {
        return detail::eval_if(0, std::move(fcs)...);
    }
}

template<typename PredT, typename F, typename = std::result_of_t<F&(std::true_type)>>
constexpr detail::fail_cond<PredT, F> fail_cond(F&& failure_cb) {
    return {std::forward<F>(failure_cb)};
}

template<typename F, typename... PredTs, typename... Fs>
constexpr decltype(auto) eval_if(F&& success_cb, detail::fail_cond<PredTs, Fs>&&... fcs) {
    return detail::eval_if(
        0, std::move(fcs)...,
        detail::fail_cond<detail::success_tag, F>{std::forward<F>(success_cb)}
    );
}
```

Usage now looks like the following:

```
template<typename Event, typename Func>
decltype(auto) register(Func&& func) {
   using can_construct = std::is_constructible<func_t<Event>, Func&&>;
   using proper_event = meta::is_in_tuple<Event, Events_Tuple>;
   return eval_if(
      [&]() { /*do proper thing*/ },
      fail_cond<can_construct>([](auto pred) { static_assert(pred, "can't construct"); }),
      fail_cond<proper_event>([](auto pred) { static_assert(pred, "improper event"); })
   );
}

// or ...

template<typename Event, typename Func>
decltype(auto) register(Func&& func) {
   return eval_if(
      [&]() { /*do proper thing*/ },
      fail_cond<std::is_constructible<func_t<Event>, Func&&>>(
          [](auto pred) { static_assert(pred, "can't construct"); }
      ),
      fail_cond<meta::is_in_tuple<Event, Events_Tuple>>(
          [](auto pred) { static_assert(pred, "improper event"); }
      )
   );
}
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/326d97c0a56ffafb)**</kbd>

The demo, while painfully contrived, shows possibilities for failure behavior at compile-time *or* runtime (n.b. failure callbacks can return values). Also demonstrated is that the value passed to a failure callback is an instance of the predicate that failed, which allows for potentially richer failure behavior and reduces the boilerplate necessary for `static_assert`s.

Comment: This is really nice and clean and definitely an improvement on my answer. A bit more machinery on the back end but that's fine because the front end is much nicer.

Comment: MSVC 14/2015 seems to fail on selecting the first overloaded function via sfinae (I believe the enable_if_t never works) so I'm wondering if there's a workaround for that.

Comment: Fixed it by replacing `is_base_of<>{}` with `is_base_of<>::value` and always passing `false_type` instead of `PredT`.

Comment: @user975989 : That loses the debuggability that was half the point of the answer. :-] I can't test locally ATM, but [this](https://godbolt.org/g/yG6mEO) works, and only involved changing the ERROR macro.

Comment: Fair enough, it suits my needs but yeah with some more typing / a macro it can be accomplished.

Comment: @user975989 : For MSVC14, all constexpr uses of traits need to change to `::value` from `{}` (that's fixed in VC15). I can't think of why constructing `PredT` would be a problem in any context though... (Or maybe that's solved by the change from `pred` to `pred.value`? `decltype(pred)::value`, worst-case...)

Comment: Actually I am just surprised as well why `PredT` is causing problems. The error I get is that `expression did not evaluate to a constant`.

Comment: @user975989 : For which expression? In my demo `return fc.failure_cb(PredT{});` is the only one where `PredT` is actually constructed, and a constant expression isn't actually needed there.. Concrete code and/or error messages would help. :-]

Comment: Yes when `fc.failure_cb()` gets called, the callback has a `static_assert` on the `pred`, but this `static_assert` fails because `pred` is not considered a constant. `pred.value` works however.

Comment: @user975989 : Ah, I see, so the problem isn't in constructing `PredT`, but rather in using a `PredT` lvalue as a constant expression. Yeah, MSVC is just lacking here – use whichever workaround you find most palatable. :-] In the future you may want to also tag your question `visual-c++` so people know to answer with broken compilers in mind. ;-]

Answer (score 3):

They are actually ambiguous when the condition is met, for both are valid.
Only the first function has a sfinae expression that can *disable* it, thus the second function is always a viable solution (that is an ambiguous one when the condition is met).

You can do this instead:

```
template <typename Event, typename Func>
auto register(int, Func &&func)
-> decltype(func_t<Event>(std::forward<Func>(func)), void()) {}

template <typename Event, typename Func>
void register(char, Func &&) {
    static_assert(meta::delay_v<Func>, "Function object cant be constructed by function");
}

template <typename Event, typename Func>
void register(Func &&func) {
    register<Event>(0, std::forward<Func>(func));
}
```

In this case, `0` (that is an `int`) will force the compiler to pick the first function up and try it. If it works, there is no ambiguity (the second one wants a `char`), otherwise `0` can be converted to a `char` and used to invoke the second function.

If you have more than two conditions, you can do this:

```
template<int N> struct tag: tag<N-1> {};
template<> struct tag<0> {};

template <typename Event, typename Func>
auto register(tag<2>, Func &&func)
-> decltype(func_t<Event>(std::forward<Func>(func)), void()) {}

template <typename Event, typename Func>
auto register(tag<1>, Func &&func)
-> decltype(func_alternative_t<Event>(std::forward<Func>(func)), void()) {}

template <typename Event, typename Func>
void register(tag<0>, Func &&) {
    static_assert(meta::delay_v<Func>, "Function object cant be constructed by function");
}

template <typename Event, typename Func>
void register(Func &&func) {
    register<Event>(tag<2>{}, std::forward<Func>(func));
}
```

The greater the number of solutions, the greater the number used with tag. The same principles applied to the `int`/`char` trick work here.

---

As a side note, as mentioned by @StoryTeller in the comments, note that `register` is a reserved keyword and you should not use it in production code.

Comment: Hmm interesting. But what about wanting to have an error for multiple conditions? For example, if `Event` is a wrong type and also for the construction of the `function`? This seems like it is constrained to some amount of error conditions, possibly even just 2.

Comment: `register` is still a reserved keyword (the committee sure likes reserving them). Just a point to consider.

Comment: @StoryTeller You are right. I get the code from the question as-is, didn't notice it was `register`. I'll mention it. Thank you.

Comment: @user975989 Added more details.

Comment: Your "more than two conditions code" doesn't actually demonstrate how to check for multiple conditions; in particular, how to give each failure condition its own error message without ever _repeating_ the conditions, which is obviously the goal.

Comment: @ildjarn Added a more meaningful example for `tag`. I'm not sure the goal is the one you mentioned (I added the `tag` trick because of a comment, how can you get the actual goal from there?). If confirmed, I can integrate the question, not a problem.

Comment: From the question: "*Furthermore, I want to have multiple error reasons that the user can receive. Since there are two failure points (providing an invalid functor and providing the wrong event type) ...*" I _assume_ not repeating the conditions is an implicit requirement, as the approach is rather straightforward when repetition is acceptable.

Comment: @ildjarn Well, with the tag he can catch the i-th type `tag<I>`, print a message (that is due to the fact that `tag<I+1>` failed) and forward the request to `tag<I-1>`. It's quite flexible a solution. CC @user975989

Comment: Your answer right now addresses `func_t<...>` _or_ `func_alternative_t<...>`, with an error only if _both_ fail; but as I understand it the question is how to address `func_t<...>` _and_ `func_alternative_t<...>`,  with an error if _either_ fails, but a different error depending on which. Maybe I'm being slow, but it's not obvious to me how to do the latter with your code (without a repetition of the failure conditions).. :-]

Comment: I agree, being able to remove repetition would be great.

Comment: @ildjarn You can do something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f459034432725dc). Does it make sense?

Comment: Hmm I think you're misunderstanding my use case, let me update the question.

Answer (score 2):

After some thought, I have found another method that seems nicer to structure.

```
template <typename Func, typename... Ts>
decltype(auto) evaluate_detector(std::true_type, Func && f, Ts&&...) {
    return f(true);
}

template <typename Func, typename... Ts>
decltype(auto) evaluate_detector(std::false_type, Func &&, Ts&&... ts) {
    return evaluate_detector(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

template <typename Event, typename Func>
void register(Func &&func) {
    using can_construct = std::is_constructable<func_t<Event>, Func>;
    using proper_event = meta::is_in_tuple<Event, Events_Tuple>;
    evaluate_detector(meta::and<can_construct, proper_event>{},
        [&](auto){/*do proper thing*/};
        meta::not<can_construct>{},
        [](auto delay){static_assert(meta::delay_v<decltype(delay)>, "can't construct"},
        meta::not<proper_event>{},
        [](auto delay){static_assert(meta::delay_v<decltype(delay)>, "improper event"});
}
```

The advantage is having all the error states in one central location and not having to create many overwritten functions. This is how I envisioned the detector idiom to be used. The types of `can_construct` and `proper_event` evaluate to `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`, or something inheriting those types so we still have overload resolution but done in a generic way.